# Move objects toward center

Tags: transforms

If I have multiple objects surrounding the center of the scene, how would I move all of them toward the center *X* units?

Example:
I have 4 gears in my scene lined up 3 units from the center in each direction. I would like to move them all towards the center without changing their size/proportions *X* units, until they begin to touch.[image: Gears]

How would I go about moving all of these objects the same distance towards the center without distorting them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check *Manipulate Center Points*, select all, press <kbd>S</kbd> and scale them down.

You can change *Pivot Point* to *3D cursor* if you want.

[image: Pivot]

Comment: That will change the size. the OP specified no size change.

Comment: Could you just watch this gif to the end?